# No se coloca la casilla de CheckBox MVC ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Estoy trabajando con `CheckBox` y tengo problemas para hacer que se vea la casilla como se muestra en la imagen:
[image]

El problema es que me sale de la siguiente manera:

[image]

Estoy siguiendo el ejemplo de esta pagina con el video que proporciona y aun así no logro hacer que se vea como en la imagen:

https://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-add-checkbox-in-dropdownlist-using-jQuery/2501#.X8zAImUzbIU

Anexo código de mi `View`:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "About";
 }
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#EmpList').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
            var selected = $("#EmpList option:selected");
            var message = "";
            selected.each(function () {
                message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
            });
            alert(message);
        });
    });

</script>
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid #e1d8d8;height:350px">
    <h2>
        Multiselect checkbox dropdown using jquery
    </h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Select Employee's Name </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("EmpList", ViewBag.Employees as SelectList, new { style = "width:100%", multiple = "multiple" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnSelected" value="Get Selected" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Estoy utilizando **MVC 4** Con **VS2015** y la **BD** es una diferente a la que proporciona la pagina
Agredezco sus comentarios ya que tengo poco tiempo trabajando con esto

Answer (score 0):

En tu vista (view) en lugar de

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmpList"..
```

intenta con

```
@Html.ListBoxFor("EmpList"..
```

El primer helper hace un render de un elemento html del tipo select simple, mientras que el segundo genera un select con la opción de multiselect

Comment: En que parte debo colocarlo?